# log4j - trigger log rolling when application starts

Tags: java, logging, log4j

With log4j, I want the behaviour of the DailyRollingFileAppender so that date-pattern based log rolling can occur when an application starts up. BUT once the application has started, I don't want it to do any automatic log rotation until the next time the application restarts. How can I configure log4j to do this?

Comment: In the end, I went for a simpler approach. In log4j.properties, I'm using org.apache.log4j.FileAppender but for the 'File' setting, instead of having a fixed name, I set it to ${LOG_FILE}.

When my application starts up and before I call PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties), I simply do:

System.setProperty("LOG_FILE", logFileName);

to give me the log file name that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification sounds like you want the application to start, create a log file of a particular date, and to keep using that until it shuts down.

If that's the case, you may want to create your own Appender implementation, perhaps deriving from [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to programatically set the logger properties by iterating over all the loggers, getting your logger and then asking ti not to roll anymore. Thats the only way I think.